# I want bigger pixbufs rendered onto GtkSourceGutter

Tags: c, windows, gtk, gtksourceview

It seems that the size of the source marks rendered with `GtkSourceGutterRenderer` are remotely tied up to the size of the text in the `GtkSourceView`. I want to have bigger pixbufs, without making the text font size bigger and to achieve that I concluded I have to subclass a widget and override its `draw` signal handler.

However I have no idea which widget to subclass on. Surely one of you knows?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's probably `GtkSourceGutterRendererPixbuf` itself that you have to subclass. If not that, then probably `GtkSourceGutterRenderer` with a lot of duplicated code from `GtkSourceGutterRendererPixbuf`.

Comment: Hello, you are most likely the only one experienced enough in the GTK+ tool chain in the entire community. My respect. I didn't receive response from the mailing lists this time, so my plan B was stack overflow. What do you mean by "With a lot of duplicated code..." ? :)

Comment: By no means am I the best person to answer this question. If no response on the mailing lists, I would suggest trying discourse.gnome.org, or #gtksourceview IRC channel on irc.gnome.org. By "with a lot of duplicated code" I meant you could probably copy most of the existing code of `GtkSourceGutterRendererPixbuf`, change the name of the class, and only change the few things you need in the `draw` function.

Comment: I will give it a try. I get it why they didn't add such a functionality, but I also think pixel-below-lines and similar functions should affect mark size.